# Manipulating a button via id

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a button add that opens a window (win) that contains some textarea and a submit button.
My problem is that i want to use  the id of the add button the function submit(btn). How can i get it?

```
var btn_add = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            width:65,
            height:30,
            text:'Add', 
            id:"btn_add",
            iconCls: 'add',
            handler: onButtonClick
        });

function onButtonClick(btn) { 
    switch (btn.id){
        case "btn_add": {
        win.show();
        break;
        }
        }


win = new Ext.Window({
        title: 'Form',
        autoScroll: true,
        y: 120,
        width: 300,
        height: 160,
        modal: true,
        closeAction: 'hide',
        items: [name,btn_submitform]
    });

var btn_submitform = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            width:75,
            height:30,
            text:'Submit', 
            id:"btn_submitform",
            handler: submit
    });


function submit(btn) {
            if(btn.id="btn_add"){
}
}
```

Comment: Can you be more precise about what your goal is? It's seems so not logic what you are doing. You have a handler on button x, where you want button y. But it never can be button y, because it's the listener of button x.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a class in order to define your button. After that, try to catch it by its alias\xtype wherever you want it.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.CoolBtn', {
    extend: 'Ext.Button',
    alias: ['widget.coolbtn'],
    title: 'Yeah!'
});

// Using Ext.create
Ext.create('widget.coolbtn');


Ext.ComponentQuery.query('coolbtn'); // Get you cmp by alias
```